# Does the function returning two arrays given an array and a test function have a name?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm looking for the name of the following function which could be written like the following in javascript:

```
function imlookingforyourname( list, f ){
    return list.reduce(
        ({left,right},x) => {
            if ( f( x ) ){
                left.push( x )
            } else {
                right.push( x )
            }
            return {left,right}
        },{left:[],right:[]}
    )
```

so

```
imlookingforyourname( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], x => x < 6  )
```

would return

```
{ left: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], right: [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ] }
```

Comment: What do you mean? Partition?

Comment: You want to name the function? Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: no, i'm looking for the name of such a function (see nina scholz answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you get an array of two arrays. It is a partition function. For example from

- ramdajs: https://ramdajs.com/0.15/docs/#partition
- lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#partition

Comment: Maybe... haskell says about Partition : http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-partition-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Partition.html BUT seems not to be restricted to two distinct sets.

Comment: the javascript implementation who needs a boolean as predicate uses only two arrays, it could be more, thinkable for grouping.

Comment: @AliceOualouest here's an almost identical Erlang API that is called "partition" http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#partition-2